# Creating a checkbook application

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a checkbook application for class that will get a transaction type such as, deposit, check, or service charges. It will then decide which transaction was clicked and get the amount and display the balance. It will also determine if there are insufficient funds. If there are insufficient funds it will not process the check and will charge a $10 dollar fee. It will also keep track of the number of deposits, checks, and service charges as well as keep up with the total amount of money for deposits, checks, and service charges. I am having trouble with that last part. Here is the explanation of what needs to be done: 
As the transactions are being entered by the user you will need to add logic to keep track of a count and amount for each Transaction Type (Deposit, Check, and Service Charge).

For the summary information you should display:

Total Number of Deposits
Total Dollar Amount of Deposits
Total Number of Checks
Total Dollar Amount of Checks
Total Number of Service Charges
Total Dollar Amount of Service Charges
Add a Summary Button to the form. When the user clicks the Summary Button you will use a single MessageBox to display the summary information to the user. You will need to build a string that will contain the count and amount for each transaction type as shown above.

Right now the number of deposits, checks, and service charges won't print out right and I can't figure out how to keep track of the total amount of money placed in deposits, checks, and service charges. Also my insufficient fund logic is not working either. My instructor says the problem is within the calculatebutton_click. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1
    Dim balance As Double
    Dim numDeposits As Long = 0
    Dim numChecks As Long = 0
    Dim numCharges As Long = 0
    Dim amountDeposits, amountChecks, amountCharges As Double
    Dim transAmount As Double
    Private Property program As String



    Private Sub CalculateBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalculateBtn.Click


        'Get transaction amount from the textbox
        transAmount = CDbl(AmountBox.Text)

        'When the check button is clicked check to see if the transaction amount is larger
        'than the balance if it is display a message box and apply a service charge of $10
        If CheckBtn.Checked And transAmount > balance Then
            balance = balance - 10
            MsgBox("Insufficient funds")

        End If

        'If the user inputs a transaction amount that is a negative number
        'display a message box
        If transAmount < 0 Then
            MsgBox("Enter a valid number")
        End If

        'Check to see if the transaction amount is numeric
        If IsNumeric(transAmount) Then
            CalculateBtn.Enabled = True
        End If

        'Decide what operation to use depending on what radio button is clicked
        If DepositBtn.Checked Then
            balance = balance + transAmount
        ElseIf CheckBtn.Checked Then
            balance = balance - transAmount
        ElseIf ServiceBtn.Checked Then
            balance = balance - transAmount
        End If

        'Print the balance
        BalanceLbl.Text = balance.ToString("C2")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitBtn.Click
        'When the exit button is clicked close the program
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AboutBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AboutBtn.Click
        'Display the 'About' information
        MessageBox.Show("Program Name: Checkbook" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine &
                        "Programmer: Stephanie Correa" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine &
                        "Description: Checkbook application to track transactions" & Environment.NewLine &
                        Environment.NewLine & "Version 2.30")
    End Sub
    Private Sub AmountBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AmountBox.TextChanged
        'If the transaction amount is a valid numeric value then enable the calculate button
        If IsNumeric(AmountBox.Text) Then
            CalculateBtn.Enabled = True
        Else
            CalculateBtn.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SummaryBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SummaryBtn.Click

        'Print summary of transactions
        MessageBox.Show("Number of Deposits: " & numDeposits & Environment.NewLine & "Number of Checks: " &
               numChecks & Environment.NewLine & "Number of Service Charges: " & numCharges & Environment.NewLine &
               "Amount from Deposits: " & amountDeposits)

    End Sub

    Private Sub DepositBtn_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DepositBtn.CheckedChanged
        'Keep track of amount of deposits and total amount of money deposited
        Dim sum As Long = 0

        sum = sum + 1
        numDeposits = sum

        amountDeposits += transAmount
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBtn_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBtn.CheckedChanged
        'Keep track of amount of checks and total amount of money from checks 
        Dim checkSum As Long = 0

        checkSum = checkSum + 1
        numChecks = checkSum

        amountChecks += transAmount
    End Sub

    Private Sub ServiceBtn_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ServiceBtn.CheckedChanged
        'Keep track of amount of service charges and amount of money from charges
        Dim ChargesSum As Long = 0
        ChargesSum = ChargesSum + 1
        numCharges = ChargesSum

        amountCharges = 0
        amountCharges += transAmount
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I think you need to update `transAmount` for each operation.  Now, it is just set in Calculate, but it seems like you ought to get the amount ( `transAmount = CDbl(AmountBox.Text)` ) before adding a deposit etc.  You should fire up the debugger/learn how to use it - most of your issues could be solved stepping thru the code and comparing what really happens vs what you thought you were coding,

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work. I did If DepositBtn.Checked Then
            transAmount = CDbl(AmountBox.Text)
            balance = balance + transAmount
        ElseIf CheckBtn.Checked Then
            transAmount = CDbl(AmountBox.Text)
            balance = balance - transAmount
        ElseIf ServiceBtn.Checked Then
            transAmount = CDbl(AmountBox.Text)
            balance = balance - transAmount
        End If

Comment: Look at the first 3 lines of Deposit click.  Read them aloud.  NumDeposits will *always* end up as `1`. the DepAmount will always use whatever happens to be in `transamount`

Comment: I understand, but if declare the variables and initialize them at 0 in the form level then the deposit amount is always more than its supposed to be.

Comment: No, what I's saying is that `numDeposits += 1` is all you need in place of those 3 lines to increment a deposit counter.  You are just assigning `1` in a roundabout fashion everytime.  For the deposit amount, you are just adding whatever is in `transAmount` - get the amount from the text controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are performing the counts in the wrong place.

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form2
'
Dim balance As Double
Dim numDeposits, numChecks, numCharges As Long
Dim amountDeposits, amountChecks, amountCharges As Double
Dim transAmount As Double
'
Private Property program As String
'
Private Sub CalculateBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalculateBtn.Click


    'Get transaction amount from the textbox
    transAmount = CDbl(AmountBox.Text)

    'If the user inputs a transaction amount that is a negative number display a message box
    If transAmount < 0 Then
        MsgBox("Enter a valid number")
    Else
        'Decide what operation to use depending on what radio button is clicked
        If DepositBtn.Checked Then
            numDeposits = numDeposits + 1
            amountDeposits = amountDeposits + transAmount
            balance = balance + transAmount
            MsgBox(transAmount & " successfully deposited")
            AmountBox.Text = ""
        ElseIf CheckBtn.Checked Then
            'When the check button is clicked check to see if the transaction amount is larger
            'than the balance if it is display a message box and apply a service charge of $10
            If transAmount > balance Then
                numCharges = numCharges + 1
                amountCharges = amountCharges + 10
                balance = balance - 10
                MsgBox("Insufficient funds, $10 service charge incurred!")
            Else
                numChecks = numChecks + 1
                amountChecks = amountChecks + transAmount
                balance = balance - transAmount
                MsgBox(transAmount & " check successfully accepted")
                AmountBox.Text = ""
            End If
        ElseIf ServiceBtn.Checked Then
            balance = balance - transAmount
            MsgBox(transAmount & " service charges successfully applied")
            AmountBox.Text = ""
        End If
        'Print the balance
        BalanceLbl.Text = balance.ToString("C2")
        'Print the Checks
        lblChecks.Text = amountChecks.ToString("C2") & "[" & numChecks & "]"
        'Print the charges
        lblCharges.Text = amountCharges.ToString("C2") & "[" & numCharges & "]"
        'Print the deposits
        lblDeposits.Text = amountDeposits.ToString("C2") & "[" & numDeposits & "]"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ExitBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'When the exit button is clicked close the program
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub AboutBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AboutBtn.Click
    'Display the 'About' information
    MessageBox.Show("Program Name: Checkbook" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine &
                    "Programmer: Stephanie Correa" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine &
                    "Description: Checkbook application to track transactions" & Environment.NewLine &
                    Environment.NewLine & "Version 2.30")
End Sub

Private Sub AmountBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AmountBox.TextChanged
    'If the transaction amount is a valid numeric value then enable the calculate button
    If IsNumeric(AmountBox.Text) Then
        CalculateBtn.Enabled = True
    Else
        CalculateBtn.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SummaryBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SummaryBtn.Click

    'Print summary of transactions
    MessageBox.Show("Number of Deposits: " & numDeposits & Environment.NewLine & "Number of Checks: " &
           numChecks & Environment.NewLine & "Number of Service Charges: " & numCharges & Environment.NewLine &
           "Amount from Deposits: " & amountDeposits)

End Sub

End Class
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. I didn't realized you could do all of the calculations as the user entered the data. Thank you so much since I am new to Visual Basic.

Comment: Your'e welcome Stephanie :) Also... The reason for doing the counts in the button-click event is because supposing the user clicks on check by mistake? and then changes to deposit? you should not calculate the numXXXXvalues until the user commits the check//deposit/service using the CALCULATE button. Then you will know you are only increasing the number count of the Right counter.